# Joining/exist query of tables Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have 2 tables TABLE1 with column names ROLLNO and STATUS & TABLE2 with column names ROLL and STATUS.

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE1 ( ROLLNO VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL, STATUS VARCHAR2(2));

INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES ('1234567890', '01');
INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES ('1234567891', '02');
INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES ('1234567895', '01');
INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES ('1234567896', '02');
INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES ('1234567897', '00');
------------------------------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE TABLE2 ( ROLLNO VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL, STATUS VARCHAR2(2));

INSERT INTO TABLE2 VALUES ('1234567890', '01');
INSERT INTO TABLE2 VALUES ('1234567891', '02');
INSERT INTO TABLE2 VALUES ('1234567892', '01');
INSERT INTO TABLE2 VALUES ('1234567893', '02');
INSERT INTO TABLE2 VALUES ('1234567894', '03');
INSERT INTO TABLE2 VALUES ('1234567898', '04');
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I just want to get the output as shown below:

```
ROLLNO           STATUS
-----------------------
1234567890         01
1234567891         02
1234567892         01
1234567893         02
1234567894         03
1234567895         01
1234567896         02
```

We need to select the rows having status 01, 02, 03 from table2 and rows from table1 having status 01,02 and
If the rows of table1 having status 01, 02 are present in table2, then we shouldn't enter duplicate rows in result table

there should be unique rows in the result.

I tried using this query but this query is wrong for this problem

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM
(
   SELECT T2.ROLLNO, T2.STATUS FROM TABLE2 T2
   WHERE T2.STATUS IN ('01','02','03')
   UNION ALL
   SELECT T1.ROLLNO, T1.STATUS FROM TABLE1 T1
   WHERE T1.STATUS IN ('01','02')
);
```

Is this correct query?

Comment: Why is that query (and the one in Connor's answer) "wrong"? Is this a homework question? If so, what are the actual constraints on what queries you can use? (Also, if you used `UNION` instead of `UNION ALL`, you could avoid the explicit `DISTINCT` step, since `UNION` outputs the distinct set of results of both queries.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
SQL> select *
  2  from (
  3  select
  4    x.*,
  5    row_number() over ( partition by rollno order by tab, status ) as x
  6  from (
  7  select t.*, 'T1' tab from table1 t
  8  where status in ('01','02','03')
  9  union all
 10  select t.*, 'T2' tab from table2 t
 11  where status in ('01','02','03')
 12  ) x
 13  )
 14  where x = 1;

ROLLNO     ST TA                              X
---------- -- -- ------------------------------
1234567890 01 T1                              1
1234567891 02 T1                              1
1234567892 01 T2                              1
1234567893 02 T2                              1
1234567894 03 T2                              1
1234567895 01 T1                              1
1234567896 02 T1                              1
```

Comment: ....Yeah this might be the query but is there any other way to write the query apart from the query you have posted

Comment: Is there any other query for this problem apart from ur query and my query